# Where to set bash settings for the user "mysql"

Tags: bash, mariadb, unixodbc

Please excuse me if the question is misleading. I'm trying to understand the way the environment settings work for the user "mysql".

I'm following [this guide](http://serge.frezefond.com/2013/12/mariadb-connect-storage-engine-access-to-oracle-11gr2) to connect an Oracle DB from a MariaDB installation.

I had managed to install the required libraries and succeed to connect from the root command line.

But when trying to connect from MariaDB I get this message:

> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   '/home/oraclec/instantclient_12_1/libsqora.so.12.1' : file not found

The same happened the first time I tried to connect from the root command line and I solved it adding these lines to the `/root/.bash_profile` file:

```
CLIENT_HOME=/home/oraclec/instantclient_12_1 ; export CLIENT_HOME
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oraclec/instantclient_12_1 ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

So, I'm trying to do the same thing for the user "mysql" but there is no a `.bash_profile` for this user.

In conclusion, where should I put these paths in order to get the user "mysql" access them?

**Note:** The server is running CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your variables to mysql from its init script. e.g `/etc/init.d/mysql`.

If you still need to create a `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`) for the mysql user, do this:

```
vi ~mysql/.bash_profile
```

If there is no home for that user, create one and update `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I tried creating a `.bash_profile` file under `/var/lib/mysql` but it doesn't work. This is the result of the `cat /etc/passwd` command: `mysql:x:498:498:MySQL server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash`

Comment: I don't have mysql installed in front of me at the moment. What if you pass your variables to mysql from it's init script? Like /etc/init.d/mysql.

Comment: That seems to be a good idea! I will give it a try. I was trying to create a script inside `/etc/profile.d`.

Answer (score 0):

It should not hurt to set it for all users in */etc/bash.bashrc*.

Instead of using LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, you can also add library path in */etc/ld.so.conf*. Don't forget to run `ldconfig` after.